# Efficiently checking for substrings and replacing them - can I improve performance here?

Tags: java

I need to examine millions of strings for abbreviations and replace them with the full version.  Due to the data, only abbreviations terminated by a comma should be replaced.  Strings can contain multiple abbreviations.

I have a lookup table that contains Abbreviation->Fullversion pairs, it contains about 600 pairs.

My current setup looks like something this.  On startup I create a list of ShortForm instances from a csv file using Jackson and hold them in a singleton:

```
public static class ShortForm{
    public String fullword;
    public String abbreviation;
}

List<ShortForm> shortForms = new ArrayList<ShortForm>();
//csv code ommited
```

And some code that uses the list

```
for (ShortForm f: shortForms){
    if (address.contains(f.abbreviation+","))
        address = address.replace(f.abbreviation+",", f.fullword+",");
}
```

Now this works, but it's *slow*.  Is there a way I can speed it up?  The first step is to load the ShortForm objects with commas in place, but what else could I do?

====== *UPDATE*
Changed code to work the other way around.  Splits strings into words and checks a set to see if the string is an abbreviation.

```
    StringBuilder fullFormed = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s: Splitter.on(" ").split(add)){
        if (shortFormMap.containsKey(s))
            fullFormed.append(shortFormMap.get(s));
        else
            fullFormed.append(s);
        fullFormed.append(" ");
    }

    return fullFormed.toString().trim();
```

Testing shows this to be over 13x faster that the original approach.  Cheers davecom!

Comment: since you have millions of strings lookups, one way could be to index them and do fulltext search for fetching all addresses matching abbreviation (I am assuming address lookups are the slowest part due to huge volume and not the replacement)

Comment: I'm replacing the on load to improve query reliability and speed.  You're right though, I could do them in batches after all rows are loaded.  Possibly worth a try.

Comment: Don't sure if this could improve performance but don't check for contains. Just replace. If it doesn't contains the string nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could really improve performance would be to use a better data structure than a simple array for storing your ShortForms.  All of the shortForms could be stored sorted alphabetically by abbreviation.  You could therefore reduce the lookup time from O(N) to something looking more like a binary search.

I haven't used it before, but perhaps the standard library's SortedMap fits the bill instead of using a custom object at all:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html

Here's what I'm thinking:

- Put abbreviation/full word pairs into TreeMap
- Tokenize the address into words.
- Check each word to see if it is a key in the TreeMap
- Replace it if it is
- Put the corrected tokens back together as an address

Comment: How will sorting them help?  I need to check for them all.

Comment: It will be much faster to look each one up.  Right now it takes 600 iterations of a loop to look each one up.  In a binary search, it would take about 6 iterations of a loop.  The even better part is you don't need to implement any of the algorithms for this;  TreeMap appears to be the implementation of SortedMap that you need and it's included in the Java standard library.

Comment: Hold up I may have misunderstood what you're doing.  I thought you were going the other way around (checking each word in your text for whether an abbreviation exists in your list).

Comment: Ah, I thought I was being dense for a minute :)

Comment: And now that I think about it some more, I think maybe you should go the other way around, especially since I'm guessing that these are fairly small pieces of text that you're searching through (addresses).  I'll put some pseudo code in my answer for what I'm thinking.

Comment: Let me know if you get what I'm thinking now, otherwise I'll write some actual code.

Comment: Ah, I did have the idea of splitting into strings, putting them into a set and checking hashes, but wasn't sure if it would be any faster.  I guess it's worth a go.

Comment: Think about it this way - right now you're doing a full text search 600 times.  That way you would be doing a lookup on each word 1 time + the overhead of the setup/tokenizing.  So if the total number of tokens is relatively small it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: This is pretty reasonable, but why use a TreeMap instead of a HashMap? TreeMap you'll get O(nlgn), hashmap you get O(n).

Comment: HashMap is probably better than TreeMap for this, agreed.  I think you meant O(1).

Comment: Cheers, I've updated my code and unit tested it for accuracy.  Now to do the performance testing...

Answer (score 2):

It would already be a bit faster if you skip `contains()` part :)

Comment: I'm guessing replace calls contains().  Doh.  Good spot.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd do this with a HashMap. The key would be the abbreviation and the value would be the full term. Then just search through a string for a comma and see if the text that precedes the comma is in the dictionary. You could probably map all the replacements in a single string in one pass and then make all the replacements after that.

This makes each lookup O(1) for a total of O(n) lookups where n is the number of abbreviations found and I don't think there's likely a more efficient method.